# Order like a list but access by a key?

Tags: c++, stl, containers

I used list to place cities into a trip. Then I iterate over
the list to display the trip itinerary. I would like to access
the cities by the name rather than by the trip order. So, I
thought I could use a map rather than a list but the key determines
the order. I would still like to control the order of the sequence
but be able to access the entries by a key.

Can these features be combined? Is there some standard way to address
this?

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
struct City{
   City(std::string a_n, int a_d):name(a_n), duration(a_d){}
   std::string name;
   int duration;
};
int main(){
    std::list<City*> trip;
    trip.push_back(new City("NY", 5));
    trip.push_back(new City("LA", 2));
    for (std::list<City*>::iterator ii=trip.begin(); ii!=trip.end(); ++ii)
        std::cout << (*ii)->name << " for " << (*ii)->duration << " days." <<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Youn should NOT use any HTML tags to format SO posts. To format code, select all the code with the mouse and type Ctrl-K.

Comment: Neil - What's the big deal about HTML tags? If it offends you, then feel free to edit the post and fix it up. No need to be angry about it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Often times you will need to compose multiple lists and maps. The common way is to store a pointer to the Cities in your by city lookup map from the pointers in your list.  Or you can use a class like [Boost.MultiIndex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) to do what you want in what I would say is much cleaner. It also scales much better and there is a lot less boiler plate code if you want to add new indexes. It is also usually [more space and time efficient](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/multi_index/doc/performance.html)

```
typedef multi_index_container<
  City,
  indexed_by<
    sequenced<>, //gives you a list like interface
    ordered_unique<City, std::string, &City::name> //gives you a lookup by name like map
  >
> city_set;
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a `map<string,int> m;`, where the values are indexes to a `vector<City>`, for example `m["NY"] == 0` and `m["LA"] == 1`.

Comment: Accessing a list via an index is an expensive operation. A map of name to iterator would be more sensible.

Comment: Changed `list` to `vector` in my answer. Thanks for bringing this up.

Answer (score 0):

Use two collections:

- A list to store the actual objects in the order you are interested in.
- A map to map names to the objects.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to use [Boost.MultiIndex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html), though that's slightly more involved. Unfortunately, I don't have time now to provide sample code; sorry.